# post data to another domain using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cross-domain

I need to post some json data to external(another domain) API using ajax which on success should return me back some json data.

This API doesn't supports GET, only POST and I have no control on it, which means I can't do JSONP or enable CORS.

Any idea how to bypass the cross-domain limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the data to your own server. Make the HTTP request to the API from your server. Relay the response.

Comment: CORS protections are implemented in the browser. The goal is to protect the user.

Comment: If the server makes the request, then the data it gets is whatever the server is allowed to access. If the client makes the request, then it gets whatever data the client is allowed to access (and can then send it to the server). If your server talks to my bank's website it won't have my password so it won't let you do anything with my money.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a proxy page: you'll send the ajax post to the proxy page, which must reside on the same domain, and the proxy page will take care of posting the data to the final destination.

A php example: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.it/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

A Java example: http://snipplr.com/view/17987/